# Using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement, Making a group the primary group

Tags: c#, active-directory, account-management

I'm trying to add a user, add them to a group, and then make that group the primary group for the user.  I've been using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement for all the AD access.
I've added the user using:

```
principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, Globs.strDomain, userOU);
UserPrincipal userPrincipal = new UserPrincipal(principalContext);
userPrincipal.Surname = this.textBox_LastName.Text;
userPrincipal.GivenName = this.textBox_FirstName.Text;
userPrincipal.SamAccountName = this.textBox_LogonName.Text;
userPrincipal.MiddleName = this.textBox_Initials.Text;
userPrincipal.DisplayName = label_DisplayName.Text;
userPrincipal.Description = this.comboBox_Description.Text;
userPrincipal.UserPrincipalName = this.textBox_LogonName.Text;
userPrincipal.SetPassword(defaultPassword);
userPrincipal.PasswordNeverExpires = true;
userPrincipal.Enabled = true;
userPrincipal.Save();
```

I then add the user to a group using:

```
using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, Globs.strDomain))
{
    GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, groupName);
    group.Members.Add(pc, IdentityType.UserPrincipalName, userId);
    group.Save();
}
```

Is there a quick way to take that group and make it the primary group for the user?  Once I have made the primary group I will remove the default group of "Domain Users".  Any help is appreciated.
-Cary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is controlled by the [attribute `primaryGroupID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679375%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It is not exposed by the default `UserPrincipal` so you must either [make your own subclass that exposes it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx) or use the more RAW underlying `System.DirectoryServices` objects and set the attribute.

(**UPDATE:** 2008 and earlier articles of MSDN magazine are no longer available via a web interface. You need to download the [January 2008 magazine's chm file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/magazine/msdn-magazine-issues) and find the article "*Look it Up: Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5*" to see the article about making a subclass)

The attribute value is the RID of the group so you need to get the [`primaryGroupToken` attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679376%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from the new group and set it to the users `primaryGroupID` attribute.